# error using shutil and rename

Tags: python, rename, shutil

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files using either rename or shutil, but I keep getting a similar error for both:

```
shutil: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'original file'
rename: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'original name' -> 'new name'
```

here is the code I've written (after reading help pages on here and elsewhere):

```
from os import listdir
from os import rename
import shutil

temp = listdir("./NSNP")
for file in temp:
    if file.endswith(".wav"):
        if file[3].isdigit():
            rename(file, "Nn_" + file[1:2] + file[4:])
        else:
            rename(file, "./NSNP/Nn_" + file[1] + file[3:])

for file in temp:
    if file.endswith(".wav"):
        if file[3].isdigit():
            shutil.move(file, "Nn_" + file[1:2] + file[4:])
        else:
            shutil.move(file, "./NSNP/Nn_" + file[1] + file[3:])
```

Comment: Use the [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) if at all possible. It'll help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: thank you! so i'm trying to use pathlib now, but i'm not sure how to add it. it works in the top bit where i list the files from the directory, but then when i try to add it in the rename function i get the same error

Comment: @Aran-Fey, is it correct to write it like so: `shutil.move(file, str(path) + "Nn_" + file[1] + file[3:])`

Comment: No. `file` is still a relative path and `move` won't be able to find the file. Use `for path in pathlib.Path('./NSNP').iterdir(): shutil.move(str(path), "./NSNP/Nn_"+path.name[1]+path.name[3:])`

Comment: @Aran-Fey, thanks for the advice. i just put the files in the same directory and did it like that. maybe i'll look into this path module when i have more time. thanks a lot!